# Как через указатели на указатели посчитать сумму двух чисел и записать в третье

Tags: c++, c, указатели, ссылки

Как через указатели на указатели посчитать сумму двух чисел и записать в третье?

Answer (score 8):

Приведу подробный код:

```
int a,b; //Переменные имеющие зарезервированную, для использованния память
int *ha,*hb; //Указатели на пока не определенную область памяти
ha = &a, hb = &b; // Указываем на какую область памяти ссылаться указателям
int **pa,**pb; // Вводим указатели, указывающие на указатели на область памяти
scanf("%d %d", ha, hb); // Считываем значения
pa = &ha, pb = &hb; // Назначаем указателям значения указателей, на которые они должны ссылаться
int c;
c = ((*(*pa))+(*(*pb))); // Звездочка "*" - получает доступ к памяти, на которую ссылается указатель (разименовувает)
printf("%d\n",c); // Выводим полученное значение
```

Answer (score 2):

Что-то такое имеется в виду?

```
void weird_sum(int **x, int **y, int **result) {
    **result = **x + **y;
}
```